# Visual Studio 2017&2019 > User Control + Started Timer = Crash :|

Tags: visual-studio, c#, forms, visual-studio-2017, timer

When I add a Timer to User Control with Visual Studio 2017 Or 2019
and Start() it 

the Visual studio Crash when add the User Control contains a Working Timer to a Form.

Comment: This question should have been submitted to Stack Overflow

Comment: Should I move it?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by Starting the Timer on its Parent Form I added on
1-Add the user control Contains timer (Control) to a Form (Form1)
2-Run the Timer (timer1) from the parent of Control (Form1)

e.g:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Control.timer1.Start();
}
```